# UIBarButtonItem Doesn't Show Up When Using MessageKit

Tags: ios, swift, messagekit

I am trying to add a navigation bar and back button to the top of a MessageViewController in MessageKit. However, the UIBarButtonItem for back button fails to show up. Below is my code

```
func setUpNavBar() {
        let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 45, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
        self.view.addSubview(navBar)
        navBar.items?.append(UINavigationItem(title: "XXXX"))
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(onCancel))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    }
```

The above function is called in `viewDidLoad()`. I think my code is correct I just can't seem to find a reason why the button won't show up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I need to replace

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

with

```
navBar.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```